# Override if condition fulfills in sleep() function in php

Tags: php

Is it possible to write sleep function with condition in php? 
Example...

```
Public function sleepy() {
sleep(100);
If(condition a) { 
Sleep(50);
} else {
 Echo 'some thing'
 }
}
```

So that the sleep(50) must be override the 100 if condition full fill?

How could I achieve similar concept, in proper programming practice?

By the way, I am typing from my iphone, sorry for any unclear code, if any...

Comment: `sleep(condition ? 50 : 100)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is only thing you are trying to do, then just move the the `sleep(100)` inside the else portion.

```
public function sleepy() {

    if(condition a) { 
        sleep(50);
    } else {
        sleep(100);
        echo 'some thing'
    }
}
```

If you are really trying to override the parameter like that, you can design you own function to execute the sleep afterward instead.